# MPFR: get sin of mpf_class

Tags: gmp, trigonometry, mpfr

I installed gmp and mpfr on my environment. Now I can successfully

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <mpf2mpfr.h>
```

Now, say that I initialize an mpf_class with some value:

```
mpf_class x = 0.73;
```

How can I use mpfr to get the sin of this number? I just need an mpf_class in, an mpf_class out. Something like:

```
mpf_class y = sin(x)
```

Which obviously doesn't work. I noticed that there is a mpfr_sin function, which I called like this:

```
mpfr_sin(x, y, MPFR_RNDN);
```

But that didn't work as well. So what am I supposed to do? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Use `x.get_mpf_t()`? Shouldn't the order of the headers be reversed?

Comment: I tried `mpfr_sin(y.get_mpf_t(), x.get_mpf_t(), MPFR_RNDN);` and it just fails with the error `no matching function call for mpfr_sin`. Am I doing something wrong..?

Answer (score 3):

`mpf2mpfr.h` is probably not what you want. It contains plenty of `#define` to replace mpf names with mpfr names in everything that follows. If you wanted a chance of having it work in your case, you would have to include `mpf2mpfr.h` before `gmpxx.h`. However, the file does not translate everything. The following lets it compile in C++03 (as long as you don't convert to `mpq_class`):

```cpp
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <mpf2mpfr.h>
void mpfr_get_q (mpq_ptr, mpfr_srcptr);
#undef mpq_set_f
#define mpq_set_f(x,y) mpfr_get_q(x,y)
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main(){
  mpf_class x=.73;
  mpf_class y;
  mpfr_sin(y.get_mpf_t(),x.get_mpf_t(),MPFR_RNDN);
}
```

but trying to print with `operator<<` will print a pointer instead of the number, for instance. Extra functions provided in C++11 would require more tweaking, it is easier to disable them: `#define __GMPXX_USE_CXX11 0` before including `gmpxx.h`.

There are mostly two ways to solve this and both start with removing `mpf2mpfr.h`. The first one is to create a temporary `mpfr_t`:

```cpp
mpf_class x=.73;
mpf_class y;
mpfr_t xx;
mpfr_t yy;
mpfr_init_set_f(xx, x.get_mpf_t(), MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_init(yy);
mpfr_sin(yy, xx, MPFR_RNDN);
mpfr_get_f(y.get_mpf_t(), yy, MPFR_RNDN);
```

The second one is to drop mpf completely and use only mpfr. Its [webpage](http://www.mpfr.org/) lists 6 C++ wrappers for it, several of which are still maintained.

Comment: Actually, I tried running the first piece of code (just copy & paste) and it yields some strange error: gmpxx.h, at line 1904: no member named _mp_size in __mpfr_struct. What does that mean? Thank you very much!

Comment: I updated my answer, but basically it is yet another sign that mpf2mpfr.h is a bad idea here.

Comment: mpf2mpfr.h was improved a bit since then, so the workaround around mpq_set_f is not needed anymore.